Is there a word or expression that describes a person who demands that something needs to be a certain way yet they wont help to get it that way?
For example: If someone demanded to another person that they will only communicate with them using a specific phone app and is fully aware that this person is unable or has forgotten the group password to access that app yet stays silent and won't help them.
What's a good word to describe this behavior or person?

"belligerent", "obstinate", "obtuse", "unreasonable", "difficult", or "high maintenance" perhaps? These are a few I thought of or found online answering similar descriptions/requests.

bloody-minded

If you say that someone is being bloody-minded, you are showing that you disapprove of their behaviour because you think they are being deliberately difficult instead of being helpful.

[Collins]

A word for such a person, one that would probably suit many similar requests, would be:

jerk


1a: an annoyingly stupid or foolish person


was acting like a jerk


1b: an unlikable person
especially : one who is cruel, rude, or small-minded


a selfish jerk

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerk

The term passive-aggressive comes to mind.  Demanding something impossible is aggressive while not helping and pretending they're unaware of the situation is passive.
This scenario strikes me as a special case of cyberbullying if you accept the definition "the use of technology to harass, threaten, embarrass, or target another person." Usually cyberbullying is made public via the Internet, but I think the term works here.

Obstructionist


a person who deliberately delays or prevents progress


